# MySQL out of Memory, but Only Through MSSQL Linked Server

Tags: mysql, linked-server

I am getting an error "**MySQL client ran out of memory**" when trying to do some simple MySQL selects or inserts from Microsoft SQL through a linked server. It was working fine for a week or so, and for some reason now throws the error every time.

If I use Toad to connect to MySQL, everything seems fine running inserts or big selects. But trying to insert just **1 row** through the MSSQL Linked server gives an error !?!?

I can "SELECT ID FROM MyTable LIMIT 10", but if I add "ORDER BY ID" to it, I get the error, even though there's an index on ID.

Is there some kind of maintenence I need to do with MySQL ?

I'm pretty much a MySQL "noob" as relates to trouble shooting. It's on a Linux box at our hosting site, with 4 gig ram.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the "fix" was to use OPENQUERY on the MSSQL server to push the processing to the client MySQL server.

-- User57112